# UserUsageReport Google API

Tags: c#, google-api

I'm using `UserUsageReport` in Google.Apis.Admin.Reports.reports_v1.

I'm getting exception *"Data for dates later than 2014-03-17 is not yet available. Please check back later"* when I tried to get the UserUsageReport on 2014-03-21.

Can anyone please let me know what will be the latest date for which the data is available?...because the date in the exception keeps changing.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solid solution for it.
But I'm using the exception to loop though the days and find the latest report.

```
  int d = 0;
  bool again;
  UsageReports y = null;
  UserUsageReportResource.GetRequest x = null;
  do
  {
    again = false;
    try
    {
    x = sr.UserUsageReport.Get("all", DateTime.Now.AddDays(d).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    y = x.Execute();
    }
    catch (Google.GoogleApiException ex)
    {
        if (d > -10)
        {
            again = true;
            d = d - 1;
        }
    }
  } while (again);
```